# $watch not triggered the second time the value changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using AngularJS, I'm trying to `$watch` the `scrollHeight` of an element (hidden inside two tables) in a directive. The behavior is very strange; the first time the value changes, it triggers my function. The second time it doesn't and then it works for good...

The `scrollHeight` I'm watching is inside a double table:

```
<table> 
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td ng-click="show()" style="cursor:pointer">Show Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table ng-show="showRow"> 
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td ng-click="showTD()" style="cursor:pointer">Show Cell</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr ng-show="showCell">
              <td id="tracker" tracker=""> Watch that</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And my directive to watch it:

```
myApp.directive('tracker', function() {
   return {
     compile : function(elem, attr, linker) {
       return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(function(){ return elm[0].scrollHeight }, function(){
             console.log(elm[0].scrollHeight);
          });
       };
     }
   }
});
```

I made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/C89Xqtap45Nuroz5AiLP?p=preview) to illustrate this behavior. If you open the console, you will see the following:

- My watched cell is getting initialized and you get the first `scrollHeight` (29)
- You click on 'Show row' and the element in your console gets displayed (so you can check the `scrollHeight` value) and the `$watch` gets triggered and displays the updated value (0) - This is correct, the element's `scrollHeight` is 0
- Now you click on 'Show cell' and you get the element (`scrollHeight` has changed (29)) but the $watch doesn't trigger the function!?! - It's only when you click again on 'Show cell' that it gets triggered and display the wrong value of 29!

I need to detect whenever my 'Watch that' gets displayed but because of that, it is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` that would to the trick, Adding and removing DOM will change run digest cycle, & after digest cycle watch gets called, then the height of element calculated properly.

**Markup**

```
<table ng-show="showRow"> 
   <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td ng-click="showTD()" style="cursor:pointer">Show Cell</td>
       </tr> 
       <tr ng-if="showCell">
          <td id="tracker" tracker=""> Watch that</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/uTwVIdAXfundtU09IuJJ?p=preview)

Comment: Very interesting! Do you know why it doesn't work with ng-show?

Comment: @ncohen I have added description in short..adding and removing DOM via `ng-if` run the digest watch gets called and height gets properly reflected

Comment: Unfortunately, it considerably slows down to display a long list... :(